# Graphics2D.drawString with float arguments from Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, graphics2d

I created a Clojure implementation of this Java [sample code](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/DrawanImageandsavetopng.htm) that draws a PNG image. My Clojure version is below. It works, but the Clojure compiler throws an error if I *don't* coerce `drawString()`'s arguments to integers. The API docs show that [`Graphics2D.drawString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#drawString-java.lang.String-float-float-) accepts float arguments but its superclass, [`Graphics.drawString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString-java.lang.String-int-int-), does not. How can I convince/trick/hint Clojure to use the float version of `drawString()`?

```clj
(defn render-image [message]
  (let [width 200 height 200
        bi (java.awt.image.BufferedImage. width height java.awt.image.BufferedImage/TYPE_INT_ARGB)
        font (java.awt.Font. "TimesRoman" java.awt.Font/BOLD 20)
        ig (doto ^java.awt.Graphics2D (.createGraphics bi) (.setFont font))
        metrics (.getFontMetrics ig)
        str-width (.stringWidth metrics message)
        str-height (.getAscent metrics)]
    (doto ig
      (.setPaint java.awt.Color/BLACK)

      ;; Compiler complains if x- and y-arguments to .drawString
      ;; are not integers. Why?
      (.drawString message
                   (int (/ (- width str-width) 2))
                   (int (+ (/ height 2) (/ str-height 4)))))
    
    bi))

(defn -main [filename]
  (-> (render-image "Hello world")
      (javax.imageio.ImageIO/write "PNG" (java.io.File. filename))))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The runtime (not the compiler) must decide which of the overloads of `.drawString` to use. The set of conversions it is willing to automatically perform can be found in [Reflector.java](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/f47c139e20970ee0852166f48ee2a4626632b86e/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L590-L621). Note that for a method parameter declared as `float` (as you wish to call), it accepts only `float`, `Float`, and `double`. But the result of dividing two integers is a rational number. So, the `float` method does not apply. And neither does the `int` method, because again there is no automatic conversion from rational to `int`.

You can see the same thing happen in a much simpler case: `(Float/valueOf (/ 1 2))`.

Since there is no automatic conversion, you must convert explicitly. You successfully did this with `int`, but apparently you don't want to call the `int` method. The solution is simple: convert with `float` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot about 'ratio' being a type in Clojure.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `drawstring` invocation to

```
  (.drawString message
               (float (/ (- width str-width) 2))
               (float (+ (/ height 2) (/ str-height 4)))))
```